# How can I read from content resolver in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentresolver

I'm new to android development and I'm working on an app that reads sms using "ContentResolver()".

The app runs perfectly unless I try to print the result of the content resolver query.

Myservice.java

```
public class MyService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };
        
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), reqCols, null, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Result: "+c.getString(0)+c.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Read:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

The app is launched using AlarmManager after 5 seconds.

If i try displaying a toast with

```
Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Read:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It runs fine.

But if I try displaying c.getString(0), it crashes.

```
Toast.makeText(context, ""+c.getString(0)+c.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Nb.
I have a feeling the error is because I'm extending Broadcast receiver, and contentResolver works only when Activity is extended.

Comment: Check if c==null before using c.

Comment: If I run the query on the mainactivty it runs fine. I added the if nevertheless and it still crashed.

Comment: `Check if c==null before using c.`

Comment: Do not do I/O like this on the main application thread. Use `WorkManager` or `JobIntentService` to do the actual work, and have your `BroadcastReceiver` simply trigger that work.